# How do I do pattern matching in strings?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

Is there a way to iterate over a comma-separated string, then doing something with the matches? So far I have:

```
for a in string.gmatch("this, is, a commaseparated, string", "(.-)[,]") do
  print (a)
end
```

The problem is the last entry in the table is not found. In C it is possible to match against `NULL` to check whether you are at the end of a string. Is there something similar in Lua?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for a in string.gmatch("this, is, a commaseparated, string", "([^,]+),?") do
    print (a)
end
```

The regex pattern `([^,]+),?` captures one or more non-comma characters that are optionally followed by a comma.